# Pushing MySQL inserts to SharePoint 2013 lists

Tags: mysql, sql, sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-workflow

**Long version**, what I've read and tried so far:

I'm trying to optimize a weekly task for some of our users. We have a CMS build using Angular that uses MySQL to store entries that are now reviewed within the CMS after which they write an evaluation in SharePoint 2013 (on prem SQL Server 2012 on one machine, SharePoint 2013 on another server all in the same domain).

The goal is to have the MySQL entries show up in a SharePoint list as soon as they are created. I'd be highly preferred if the arrival of a new MySQL entry could spark a 2013 WorkFlow (send email, update webparts, log changes to task-lists etc).

The CMS currently does have NuSoap installed to feed a mobile application, but SharePoint Designer has some issue with reading all the fields from the WSDL and I [read that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx) this is one of the preferred methods to obtain pushed data into workflows, but I could not get SharePoint to usa the call http web service with success. Adding the WSDL as data source did only include the index and did not display anything in a webpart.

An alternative option was using ODBC on the SQL Server to grab the data in a SQL view from the Linked Server and copy the new entries over when they arrive. I have managed to make a view that can be used as External Content Type in SharePoint Designer 2013 and than can successfully be displayed in SharePoint as an External List.

Given the nature of the submissions, the content cannot be altered in the MySQL database. But I do want users to be able to add notes and other fields in SharePoint.
I found in two (older) [Sources](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bcs/archive/2010/01/20/using-sharepoint-workflows-with-business-connectivity-services-bcs.aspx) ([the one on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408903/can-an-external-list-have-event-receivers)) that it is not possible to fire a WorkFlow when using External Content Types, since "SharePoint does not own the data", but SQL Server does, so you cannot attach a workflow or have a workflow be notified when an entry is added.

==
**TL;DR version**

How do you make a "copy" of MySQL data from a read only source into a SharePoint 2013 List?
Neither the business data connection tools (web services as data source) nor the External Content Type solutions seem to result into a solution with default SharePoint List with attached Workflows.
For this specific solution push or frequent updates are required.